# UIColor Limitations or Bugs on iPhone 3.0

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uicolor

I'm working with some colors, and they don't appear to be correct at all.  The attached Images show the expected result, and the actual simulator, and on-device result.  As you can see there appears to be quite a difference between what the Gimp thinks RGB(0, 16, 60) is and what the output I'm getting from `[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:16.0 blue:60.0 alpha:1.0];`

Since my alpha is 1.0 I don't believe I have any color mixing with the background going on.

Any suggestions on what's going on here are welcome.[alt text http://img200.imageshack.us/img200/3710/picture4uu.png](http://img200.imageshack.us/img200/3710/picture4uu.png)

iPhone Result:

[alt text http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/9264/picture3xb.png](http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/9264/picture3xb.png)

Comment: Clearly, the authors of the application you're using assumed their users were blind and would never notice the difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just about every color method in iPhone OS takes a value from 0.0–1.0, not 0.0–255.0. To get the color you're looking at in The GIMP, divide each of your values by 256; thus, the correct UIColor method call would be `[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0625 blue:0.2344 alpha:1.0]`.

Comment: So in otherwords, RTFM.   Your answer is correct, thanks for not just writing, "see Apple documentation".

Comment: Just a note for why you get the result you saw in case has similiar problems and comes across this question... colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha: chops values to the range 0..1, so 16.0 and 60.0 both become 1.0 making [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0] which you'll notice gives the same result.